# How to create DataFrame from List \seq collection using spark createData Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
#1 val tupleData = List(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000"))
    sc.createDataFrame(tupleData).toDF("col1","col2") // perfectly fine 
#2    val intData = List(1,2,3)   
   sc.createDataFrame(intData).toDF("col1") // this line causing compile time issue
```

Have questions on #2.. Why unable to create DataFrame for List[Int]. In #1 i am creating List of tuples..and able to create DF using createDataFrame option. This method is accepting in Product type. Why it is NOT accepting #2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](data: Seq[A]): DataFrame = {}
```

If you see above createDataFrame function that takes only subtype of Product or TypeTag.

```
#1 val tupleData = List(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000"))
    sc.createDataFrame(tupleData).toDF("col1","col2") // perfectly fine
```

Tuple2 is subtype of Product trait that why it is accepting List of tuple2 for creating dataframe.

```
#2    val intData = List(1,2,3)   
      sc.createDataFrame(intData).toDF("col1")
```

In this you are passing List of type Int & Int is not sub type of Product or TypeTag.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your `Int`s to a `Tuple1` :

```
createDataFrame(List(1,2,3).map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("col")
```